# Webrtc Aecm for Android

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I'm developing a Sip client for android and i want to implement the Aecm module from webrtc but i don't understand how to do properly.
I've 2 runnable class, one for AndroidRecord (microphone) and one for AudioTrack (speaker), so i don't know how and where i've to call that api :

```
int32_t WebRtcAec_BufferFarend(void *aecInst, const int16_t *farend, int16_t nrOfSamples);
int32_t WebRtcAec_Process(void *aecInst, const int16_t *nearend, const int16_t *nearendH, int16_t *out, int16_t *outH, int16_t nrOfSamples, int16_t msInSndCardBuf, int32_t skew);
```

BufferFarend is the AudioTrack buffer? and the buffer that will be written on AudioRecord have to pass into "WebRtcAec_Process" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WebRtcAec_BufferFarend():**

This is used to supply the webRTC aecm with the played frame. You just need to put the played frame and the number of samples on that frame.

**WebRtcAec_Process():**

This is used to remove the echo from the captured data. This function basically compare your MIC captured data with the previous inserted played frame.

Now the main question is from where to compare the data. For that the function has skew. It specify the compare moment of data or the tail-length. If you calculate it successfully you will get good result.

**For Real-Time:**

In real-time it's pretty difficult to measure the good skew. Because the data that comes and played are not synced with one another. There you have to take consideration of playing frame after receiving audio data and the time of capturing data in MIC. Also you have to take measure of the playback delay from your PC/device. You should also consider to compare the block by block (ms) data of a frame for good result in echo cancellation. It's better to use atleast 10 ms block.

Comment: could you please provide the calculations for Delay Estimate and Skew parameters for Android devices?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have wrote a detail algorithm with calculation in my blog. You can visit the link, http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2014/11/googles-webrtc-aecm-for-android-mobile.html. It is big so can not put here. Enjoy!